# Can't click inside any window application!

Tags: window-manager

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I can click to open an application like Firefox or LibreOffice Writter and once the app opens I can't click inside...I can't click open or close, or refresh or anything.

One work around is I can log out and log in and now I can click but I have to log out every time I turn the PC on. If I use firefox browser it will freeze the system within 2 min.

Tried downloading Chromium just to go online but while downloading Chromium the system freeze again.

BTW if I log out and log in and I don't use the internet everything will work fine.

Just downloaded and reinstalled Ubuntu again with the same issue. In the virtualBox Ubuntu just works fine but when I install it on a TEST pc I have the issue is there.

Comment: Could you please clarify which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: you should also include what video card/s you are using, it could be relevant.

Comment: I've experienced such frequent freezes in the past.. and about _"click doesn't work"_ try pressing Alt + Tab keys.. I don't know why, but that works for me... check this link too: [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 13):

Something similar happen to me a while ago while i was fooling around with the compiz configurations and i solved it by doing the following:

Run the following commands in the terminal, `compiz --replace &` and after it `unity --reset` and log out and in again.

Hope it helps, next time try providing more info about your setup, version, shell and some hardware related.

Comment: FYI: I get 'ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated'.

Comment: I didn't need the second part. The first part was enough to fix things for me. Thanks

Comment: I dont have unity or compiz