# My mouse starts acting like it can't click on things?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu. With only one monitor everything works perfect. But when I switched away from the default driver so I could use two monitors it started acting funny. After a while on the computer the mouse will stop working when you click into a new window. You have to backtrack to where your last window was, close that (or dock it to the window you want to type in, in the case of a ff tab) and then use your mouse or keyboard. After it starts doing that it'll only be a few minutes until you've tied yourself into a proverbial click knot and have to manually restart the computer. I've tried using all three drivers here but the issue happens on all of them.

[image]
[image]

<s>I used Cubby's post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/72112/mouse-clicks-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu). This worked:</s>

```
sudo apt get install --reinstall inputattach
```

**edit** [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411291/cant-click-inside-any-window-application) is what fixed it.

```
compiz --replace &
unity --reset
```

It's still broke. I thought those things fixed it but they didn't. Sometimes it breaks after a couple minutes. Sometimes it takes a couple hours. When it happens I can type in one window but only click in another.

**update** - It's a couple weeks later and I'm still having the problem. Under Additional Drivers > NVidea Corporation there is a new version of NVidea binary driver that I'm using. I believe it's 375.0 but I am not going to check because doing so will likely cause this issue to start happening. I tried switching the HDMI cables so my left monitor is now my right and vice versa but that didn't work. The only thing that helps at all, sometimes, is to

```
ctrl + alt + t
unity --replace
```

Half the time that works. The other half I have to restart the computer. On some forums the problem was the users mouse but I checked with a different mouse and get the same problem.

Can someone help please?