# A Javascript error has occurred in the main process VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

It was working fine before and all of a sudden I the toolbar relevant to VSCode wasn't showing up at the top of my screen so I decided to close VSCode but now this is happening. I've been getting it every time I try to open VSCode

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: EIO: i/o error, write
    at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:745:20)
    at SyncWriteStream._write (internal/fs.js:75:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:329:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:315:5)
    at SyncWriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at Console.warn (console.js:51:16)
    at r.error (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:209:58)
    at t.error (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:212:68)
    at Q (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:492:874)
    at e.invokeFunction (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:198:919)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:493:824
    at n.Class.derive._creator.done (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:88:254)
    at Object.g [as _notify] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:83:343)
    at Object.enter (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:86:418)
    at n.Class.derive._creator._run (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:87:719)
    at n.Class.derive._creator._chainedError (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:87:78)
    at n (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:84:929)
    at Object.g [as _notify] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:83:170)
    at Object.enter (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:86:418)
    at n.Class.derive._oncancel._run (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:87:719)
    at n.Class.derive._oncancel._error (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:87:236)
    at Object.g [as _notify] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:83:170)
    at Object.enter (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:86:418)
    at n.Class.derive._oncancel._run (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:87:719)
    at n.Class.derive._oncancel._error (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:87:236)
    at t.handlers.(anonymous function) (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:154:970)
    at e.onMessage (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:155:800)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:154:171
    at e.fire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:102:496)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:160:844)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:560:20)
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but to no avail. I'm running Ubunutu 16.04 LTS. Any tips?

Edit: After a minute or two, a window pops up that says I have another instance of VSCode running and should close all of them before starting it again. How would I go about doing this? Tried doing `killall code` but that didn't seem to work as `code` is probably not the right thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by doing

`compiz --replace &` (from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411291/cant-click-inside-any-window-application))

and then

`sudo killall code`

and then re-opening code. It doesn't work if I close the terminal that I used for the first command.